# Can I add a download button to a landing page?

Tags: marketing-cloud, landing-page

I have a .pdf file I'd like people to be able to download it from a landing page. Is it a possible thing to do?

Comment: Can you be more specific which Salesforce Cloud this is about?

Comment: Marketing Cloud

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can upload the file in content builder, and reference it's URL. Once uploaded, you can click on the "copy" button within the asset:
[image]
And use this in an `<a href="https://image.mc.example.com/...">PDF</a>` link within your landing page.

Comment: The above method suggested by Lukas is considered to be better [hosting your PDF in MC]; rather than just placing an externally hosted PDF link in emails.